# MySQL - How can I get Join data twice from one table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables, `tbl_users` and `tbl_pagecontent`. Inside `tbl_pagecontent` I have two columns 'UserCreated' and 'UserModified' which contain IDs of users inside `tbl_users`, and in `tbl_users` I have 'ID', 'Username',etc.

I guess my question is, how can I query a row, so after the page details (title, content, etc.), I also get the username that created and the username that modified (using corresponding IDs). I tried using a Left Join, but that only works for only one link.

Comment: You can use `union`.Can you post you table structure

Comment: Can you post the query you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add two left joins to `tbl_users`, one from `UserCreated` & one from `UserModified`

```
select u1.Username as CreatedBy, u2.Username as ModifiedBy
from tbl_pagecontent 
left join tbl_users u1 on u1.id = tbl_pagecontent.UserCreated
left join tbl_users u2 on u2.id = tbl_pagecontent.UserModified
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign two different alias to the same table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_pagecontent p, tbl_users u1, tbl_users u2
WHERE p.usercreated = u1.userid
AND p.usermodified = u2.userid
```

**(OR)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_pagecontent p
LEFT JOIN tbl_users u1 ON p.usercreated = u1.userid 
LEFT JOIN tbl_users u2 ON p.usermodified = u2.userid
```